# How to prevent laces from untieing?

Tags: clothing

My shoe laces generally untie on their own.

The only way I found is to tie them twice, but that makes it difficult to untie.

Tell an easier way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, rolled shoe laces (the round ones) frequently undo themselves, and I've never found a way to stop them doing it, no matter how hard I tried, but flat fabric (not leather) shoe laces don't. Not a hack, but maybe buy some more shoe laces if yours are the round ones?

Comment: Thnx but i knew about it, but we can't choose shoes according to laces.

Comment: @Displayname Of course not, but you can always replace the laces. That's what I do...

Comment: Ya, its the only one way left.